# Trying to group quantities based off an ID

Tags: sql, oracle, grouping

We have two columns one with ID and another with QTY. And the layout goes along the lines of:

```
ID        QTY
-------------
123       456
123       634
123      4235
234        67
234       735
234       666
```

What I am trying to do is add up all the numbers based off the ID so it would look like:

```
ID        QTY
-------------
123      5325
234      1468
```

I currently have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT CLIENT_ID, ID, QTY_ON_HAND,
SUM(QTY_ON_HAND)
FROM
(select CLIENT_ID, ID, QTY_ON_HAND
FROM INVENTORY
WHERE CLIENT_ID = '(CLIENT ID HERE)')
GROUP BY QTY_ON_HAND
```

It would be appreciated if anyone can tell me simple way on how to do this.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`, `SUM()`.

Comment: Another hint - there are some good, basic SQL tutorials available free on the web. This sort of thing is often one of the first lessons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have a test DB at hand, but it should be this:

```
select
    ID,
    sum(QTY) as TOTAL
from
    YourTableName
group by
    ID;
```

YourTableName ... name of data table with two columns ID, QTY. Be aware of whole table name, it can be also something like dbo.yourtablename, etc.

Comment: Thank you! I had to include the dbo before the table name but it works like a charm.